# Ensure image is zoomed out

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying some images as backgrounds on a webpage but the image isn't displaying entirely 'zoomed out'. Instead, it's taking just the left side for example.

How can I make the image display completely? Is it to do with the resolution?

```
#kitchenimage{
      width:100%;
      background: url("siteimages/kitchenimage.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
      padding:200px 0;
}
```

The image is 3249 x 1679.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which option prefer, define one of the following:

```
background-size: cover;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: contain;
```

The first will scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image, leaving some parts of the background cropped while keeping aspect ratio.
The second won't keep the aspect ratio and will cover the background without any cropping.
The third will scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the background area.

Comment: Perfect, used the second option. Are there any differences between the 3 options?

Comment: @Luke Added comments to the post.

Comment: @Luke Yes. The first option will scale the image proportionally until the entirety of the background area is covered. Some clipping may occur. The third option will scale the image proportionally until the height and width can no longer fit in the background area, and then it stops. There will be no clipping but the "black bars" effect will be present, if you know what I mean.